# How do I show a full sized of image, from a click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I'm using a `GridView` to display some tabular data in a `WinForm` application.
I have a column for the table, which is stored as a VarBinary data type, which contains my image data.

How do I show the full size image, when one of them is clicked on?

Comment: I apologize for my bad English

Comment: where should they be shown?

Comment: @VladL For Example in a pop-up window

Answer (score 6):

I've just had to do similar thing, so I'll just give you the code

```
Form frm = new Form();
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
//pb.Image = Image.FromFile("my.bmp");
pb.Image = myImage;
pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
frm.Controls.Add(pb);
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: @Ehsan you have to load the image somehow into the object of type Image. the commented line shows how to load it from the file. I don't know how you do take the images from the database

Comment: @VladL please how do I pass image form `picturebox1` in `form1` to `picutebox2` in `form2` using same scenario  ? thanks a lot

Comment: @sam the quick and dirty solution is to make the picutebox2 public, then you can access it from the form1 (if you create form2 in form1 ofcourse)